# In PHP convert date in to time format output

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my database field there in date and time saved using `time();` function.

I want to compare that one with given date in date format like '20/02/2015 '

my query is like:

```
select view,optin,insertTime,isUnique from sg_page_report as PR where insertTime='20/02/2015'"
```

where `insertTime` contains different format date like '1393587636'

How can I resolve this one?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(insertTime)='2015-02-20'
```

Or you can do it like

```
$ts=mktime(0,0,0,2,20,2015);     // or
//$ts=strtotime('20/02/2015');  // inefficient
```

And your query can be modified to look like

```
WHERE insertTime=$ts
```